# How can I run Raycasts on the server instead of on client?

Tags: lua, roblox, raycasting

I am trying to create a simple first person shooter in Roblox, but all the examples I can find use client side RayCast to determine if a shot hits another object or player.

The client then informs the server of the hit by calling a function, and the server function then subtracts health from the player.

But I would like to have the server do the raycast instead of the player, to make cheating a little harder. (The cheat could still use an aimbot, but it couldn't just order the server to decrease the health of any player.)

```
local Raycastparams = RaycastParams.new()
Raycastparams.FilterType = Enum.RaycastFilterType.Blacklist
Raycastparams.FilterDescendantsInstances = {game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character}
Raycastparams.IgnoreWater = true
local camera = workspace.CurrentCamera


while wait(1) do
    
    -- is viewportcenter really middle of the screen where crosshair is?
    local viewportCenter = Vector2.new(camera.ViewportSize.X/2, camera.ViewportSize.Y/2)
    
    
    local viewportRay = camera:ViewportPointToRay(viewportCenter.X, viewportCenter.Y)
    local raycastResult = workspace:Raycast(viewportRay.Origin, viewportRay.Direction * 1000, Raycastparams)
    
    
    print(raycastResult)

end
```

I have put this in a StarterPlayerScript, it tells me in the console every second what I'm looking at. But how do I confirm this server-side?

Just for the sake of an example, how can the server *also* report back what the material is that the camera is looking at?

Comment: What have you tried? What isn't working?  Have you read [Roblox's guide on raycasting](https://create.roblox.com/docs/mechanics/raycasting) yet?

Comment: Conceptually though, you can adapt the examples you've seen. When the player clicks, the client fires a remote event with the vector of where they are looking, then the server catches that signal and performs the raycast and validates that the player can hit it. And update health accordingly. However, be aware that there is a delay between when the remote event fires and the server gets it. During that time, the players will have moved, so be careful trusting the server as the infallible source of truth on collisions.

Comment: @Kylaa, yes, I have read the guide on raycasting, but as far as I can tell, it's about raycasting on the client side? At this page https://create.roblox.com/docs/scripting/luau/parallel-luau there is something about server side raycasting. I have put that script under ServerScriptService/Actor, but how do I connect it to what happens on the client side? I'm maybe not the brighest, but I can easily say Roblox is the most challenging programming task I've set upon.

Comment: @Kylaaa, I have a working example of Raycasting on the client, a while - loop which every second tells me what the camera is looking at, and the material "line of sight" hits.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special about performing a [raycast](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/WorldRoot#Raycast) on the server vs the client. It is afterall, just a projection from one Vector3 in the direction of another Vector3.  In your example, you've used the Camera's position and then calculated the "look vector" of the camera. While the server *does* have a camera, it does not follow any player. So in order to accomplish your goal, you may need the client to provide some information before the server can execute the raycast. And you do need to consider that there are networking delays for round-trip communications, so performing the raycast on the server might not be the most accurate.

So to make this example work, you need to set up a few things :

- **Put a [RemoteFunction](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/RemoteFunction) in ReplicatedStorage**, we will use this to communicate that the player fired a weapon, and for the server to communicate back to the player.
- **Put a LocalScript into StarterPlayer > StarterCharacterScripts**, this will start executing when the player's character is added to the Workspace, and we'll use it tell the server that we've fired a weapon.
- **Put a Script in ServerScriptService**, this will initialize the RemoteFunction's server callback.

In your LocalScript :

```lua
-- define some services
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local UserInputService = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local Workspace = game:GetService("Workspace")

local camera = Workspace.CurrentCamera

-- find the RemoteFunction
local RemoteFunction = ReplicatedStorage.RemoteFunction

-- listen for when the player clicks
UserInputService.InputBegan:Connect(function(input, gameProcessed)
    if input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.MouseButton1 then
        -- get the look vector based on the camera's position and orientation
        local look = camera.CFrame.LookVector
        
        -- tell the server that we've clicked and where we're looking
        local material = RemoteFunction:InvokeServer(look)
        print("the server has reported to the client that the clicked material is : ", material)
    end
end)
```

In your Script :

```lua
-- define some services
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local Workspace = game:GetService("Workspace")

-- find the RemoteFunction
local RemoteFunction = ReplicatedStorage.RemoteFunction

-- define some raycast parameters
local raycastParams = RaycastParams.new()
raycastParams.FilterType = Enum.RaycastFilterType.Exclude
raycastParams.IgnoreWater = true

local RAYCAST_LENGTH = 1000 -- studs

-- listen for when a player fires a weapon
RemoteFunction.OnServerInvoke = function(player : Player, lookVector : Vector3)
    -- do some quick data sanitation
    local character : Model = player.Character
    if not character or character.Parent == nil then
        warn(player.Name .. " is trying to fire their weapon but their character isn't spawned")
        return
    end

    -- update the raycast params to ignore the player that is firing this signal
    raycastParams.FilterDescendantsInstances = { character }

    -- perform the raycast based on the player's character's position
    -- note: the length of the lookVector is important as the engine does not treat the vectors as rays, but checks for collisions only along the length of the vector.
    local origin : Vector3 = character.Head.Position
    local result : RaycastResult = Workspace:Raycast(origin, lookVector * RAYCAST_LENGTH, raycastParams)

    if result then
        local instance = result.Instance
        if instance then
            local hitPlayer = Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(instance.Parent)
            -- this assumes that all targets are Player character models, this may not be true if you have NPCs
            if hitPlayer then
                print("We've hit " .. hitPlayer.Name)
                local DAMAGE = 10
                hitPlayer.Character.Humanoid.Health -= DAMAGE
            end

            -- return the hit material to the client, because they want it
            return result.Material
        end
    end
    
    -- return some default  
    return Enum.Material.Air
end
```

Comment: I added a RemoteFunction and let the name just stay "RemoteFunction". (This seemed "magical" to, I don't understand what I'm doing here.) Then, when I ran the game, I got "local result : RaycastResult = Workspace:Raycast(origin, lookVector, raycastParams)" <-- that *result* became *nil. So the scripts seemed to start and everything, but the result from the Raycast didn't come out to an object. (Also, but not important now I guess, I got a warning in that *Enum.RaycastFilterType.Blacklist* is deprecated.)

Comment: Also, I don't understand the call to *RayCast()*  - in the documentation it says *local raycastResult = workspace:Raycast(rayOrigin, rayDirection)*  . Is the third argument may optional? And is the *local result : RaycastResult* an explicit cast to type *RayCastResult* ?

Comment: I addded watches and debugged the RayCast() line, all 3 arguments look OK to me, with vector values in them and the third looking like it was setup. Just to check, I removed the third argument and tried again, but RayCast() still returned **nil**

Comment: Hm, apparently if nothing "eligible" is hit with a RayCast(), it returns **nil**. So checking for nil before trying to do anything else cleared it up. It still doesn't report hits exactly the way I expected, but I think I work things out from here. Thanks!

Comment: One thing I still don't understand is - with the code above, it's the character *doing the shooting* which has its health decreased. How can I instead make it so it's the character *shot at* having its health decreased?

Comment: Also, the ray won't hit the objects in my world, only the ground. (Is that because the objects only exist client side yet, and I haven't created them in the server world, too?)

Answer (score 0):

unity can build dedicated server
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/dedicated-server.html
run it as your gamelogic server
enum you client type such as {client, host} then do their own behaviour.

Comment: Ok, but I wonder about Roblox, not Unity.